# Say "you guys" to a group of people

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, word-usage, phrase-meaning

Can we say "guys" to a group of people, that group possibly including women?

Example sentence: *I am looking forward to see you guys then!*

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many, many factors; the country you are in, the social grouping, the formality of the occasion, the presence or otherwise of any strong feminists.

I suggest you avoid calling women guys. It's safer in all situations. Only call men 'you guys' if you have a comfortable relationship with them. If they don't know you well they may find the term too familiar.